# Django query objects by subset of possible foreign keys

Tags: django

I have a query: topics, that looks like

```
topics = Topic.objects.filter(top_is_published=True, top_last_used_date__range=(issue.wir_issue_date - timedelta(days=7), issue.wir_issue_date))
```

And I want all the articles which have one of the objects in 'topics' as their foreign key. When I try to use a lookup like:

```
articles = News.objects.filter(top_name=topics)
```

or something similar, I get the error "ValueError: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing." I've searched for an example, but I can't find one.

Thanks for any help.

```
class News(models.Model):
    top_name = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name = 'topic Name')
    art_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name = 'title')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.art_title
```

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    top_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name = 'name')
    top_is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name = 'published')
    top_last_used_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name = 'Last Featured Date')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.top_name
```

Comment: can you add your models? also just a wild guess - wouldnt converting `topics` to list help, ie. `filter(top_name=list(topics))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to check if your articles are `in` your topics?

try this:

```
articles = News.objects.filter(top_name__in=topics)
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks.